# How do I build the truth table of the Boolean function that equals 1 and if x.y.z = 0?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, boolean-algebra

I need to build the truth table of the Boolean function F(x, y, z) that equals 1 if and
only if x.y.z = 0.

I'm having trouble understanding the wording as it seems confusing.

In this, it returns true only if all of the inputs are 0.
That is, x is 0, y is 0 and z is 0.

So do I just build a truth table with x, y, z, and x.y.z?

Thank you so much in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you draw a table with the four columns $x,y,z,x.y.z$. The left three columns should contain all possible combinations of $x,y,z$ – $8$ of them. Then for the $0,0,0$ row you should put $1$, and for all the other rows put $0$.

Comment: Thank you, so much. :)

Comment: @DineshGupta Now, please accept my answer. There's a tick you can see; click it and it should turn green. Do nothing to this question afterwards.